# Linq Sum issue when NCrunch Testing

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, typemock

When running a unit test with NCrunch I am having difficulty resolving certain behaviour.

If I have a line of code such as

```
itemWeight += ChildItems.Sum(ci => ci.ItemWeightManufacturedInTonnes);
```

versus

```
ChildItems.ForEach(ci => itemWeight += ci.ItemWeightManufacturedInTonnes);
```

When running with NCrunch and MBUnit the test is failing with

> System.ArgumentException: Delegate to an instance method cannot have
>   null 'this'.

when using the first line of code.

By changing to the second line of code, where ForEach is a handcrafted method to apply function to each item in a collection, then the tests work as expected.

The underlying collection is an ObjectSet from EntityFramework if that makes a difference.

The ChildItems are mocked items using TypeMock.  Perhaps Linq functions require something that is not being configured correctly.

Could someone explain why there would be a difference in behaviour please.

UPDATE:

Foreach function:

```
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

        foreach (T item in source)
        {
            action(item);
        }
    }
```

ChildItems

```
    public EntityCollection<Item> ChildItems
```

Comment: I can´t see any `this`-reference in non of your code-examples. Anyway what do you mean by handcrafted `ForEach`? Isn´t this the method that exists on `List<T>`already? Why implement an own one?

Comment: It is not List<T>.  It is equivalent to that but works on other collection types.  That is the problem, I also cannot see a reference to 'this'.  Perhaps it is due to the fact that the items are TypeMocks.

Comment: Well, in this case it´s impposible to answer this question without knowing the code of `ForEach` and what `ChildElements` is.